# Proof for $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+1}{b+1}$

Tags: inequality

Supposing $b > 0$ and $a < b$, how could I prove:

$$ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+1}{b+1} $$

Comment: Related: [How to prove that adding $n$ to the numerator and denominator will move the resultant fraction close to $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3102218/42969)

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to
$$ab + {\color{red}a} < ab +{\color{red}b}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{a(b+1)}{b(b+1)} = \dfrac{ab+a}{b(b+1)}$. However, $\dfrac{a+1}{b+1} = \dfrac{(a+1)(b)}{(b)(b+1)} = \dfrac{ab+b}{b(b+1)}$.

If $a<b$ then what about $ab+a$ vs $ab+b$?

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.