# How do I prove that this inequality result holds for all positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

How I can prove that this:
$$ \frac{1}{2} < \frac{2}{3} < \frac{3}{4} < \frac{4}{5} < \frac{5}{6}<...<\frac{n+1}{m+1}<...$$
always holds when $n < m$ and $n$ and $m$ are positive integers?

I started writing this $\frac{n}{m}<\frac{n+1}{m+1}$ but then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3373528/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed It does. Thank you! it was very helpful.

Comment: You can search for similar questions [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%20nm%20%3C%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7Bm%2B1%7D%24), see also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24882/42969.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $$\frac{n+1}{m+1}-\frac{n}{m}=\frac{m-n}{m(m+1)}>0$$ for $m>n>0.$

Answer (score -1):

This a high-school standard exercise on inequalities:

As all numbers are positive,
$$ \frac nm<\frac{n+1}{m+1}\iff n(\not m+1)<m(\not n+1)\iff n<m. $$

Comment: You answered an identical question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3373570/42969.

Comment: @MartinR: I didn't remember. Anyway,   I generalised the answer in this other  post. Here I tried to make it as short and expressive as possible.